# The go 1.5 trace command

Tags: graph, go, trace, demo

The Go 1.5 release note says,

> The new "go tool trace" command enables the visualisation of  program traces generated by new tracing infrastructure in the runtime.

This is really exciting, and I want to know more about it. But its official document at https://golang.org/cmd/trace/ is really dry.

Found that [Rob Pike complained about it](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11605), requesting that *"shortly after the 1.5 release, there should be a blog post about the feature."*

If anyone has posted/spotted such a blog, please add a link here. Or, if you like to answer directly here, it is also welcome as well.

Thanks

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two ways you can generate trace files.

**Method 1**

1. Add following line at the start of your program

   ```
   f, err := os.Create(time.Now().Format("2006-01-02T150405.pprof"))
   if err != nil {
       panic(err)
   }
   defer f.Close()

   if err := trace.Start(f); err != nil {
       panic(err)
   }
   defer trace.Stop()
   ```
2. build the program

   > go build
3. Run your program (for example `./myprogram`)
4. Run go trace.

   > go tool trace myprogram 2015-08-21T115354.pprof

**Method 2**

1. Write a testing function utilizing testing package.
2. Run Test with trace flag

   > go test -trace trace.out
3. Run trace tool with generated .test and .out file

   > go tool trace pkg.test trace.out

**In both cases your browser will open something like this**

[image]
[image]
[image]