# What are the differences between ranging over a buffered channel and non-buffered channel in Go?

Tags: go, channel

I am trying something similar to the below pattern:

```
func sendFunc(n int, c chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        c <- i
        fmt.Println("Pushed")
    }
    close(c)
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int, 10)
    go sendFunc(10, c)
    // Receive from the channel
    for i := range c {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

The output appears to be sync, like this:

```
Pushed
Pushed
Pushed
Pushed
Pushed
Pushed
Pushed
Pushed
Pushed
Pushed
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

And if I change the buffered channel to a non-buffered channel:

```
c := make(chan int)
```

the result seems to be async:

```
Pushed
0
1
Pushed
Pushed
2
3
Pushed
Pushed
4
5
Pushed
Pushed
6
7
Pushed
Pushed
8
9
Pushed
```

why it behaves differently?

**Updated**

So my scenario is that: in the receiver a request will be made every time new data is received from the producer, the result shows that the scheduler does not start receiving until all data has been sent to the channel (given a buffered channel with enough space), unless the producer is paused (e.g. by calling `time.sleep()`). Therefore I ended up using the non-buffered channel so that the time to wait for responses and the time to process data in the producer can overlap which leads to better concurrency.

Comment: You are observing effects of the goroutine scheduler.  Add a time.Sleep(time.Second) to the send loop and observe what happens.

Comment: I would like to suggest you to run go trace tool and visualize the trace. It will help you to understand how two go routines ran. Refer this answer on how to use trace tool https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32131339/the-go-1-5-trace-command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Cerise Limón already stated: this is an effect of how the runtime schedules go routines. Basically a go routine is run as long as it doesn't block or returns. So the call `go sendFunc(10, c)` will execute until it blocks or returns. If you put a `<-time.After(1)` in the `sendFunc`, the function will suddenly block and you will have the effect that the scheduler will schedule another routine.

here is a little example on the playground:
https://play.golang.org/p/99vJniOf3_

The question which one is better is hard to answer. And disclaimer: I am by far not an expert on this, but I guess it is a tradeoff. While a smaller buffer reduces the time a single message stays in a buffer, it triggers a re-scheduling of go routines, which general costs some time.

A larger buffer can on the other hand increase the message latency through the buffer but on the other hand improve the throughput. Also you can preproduce a lot of messages, which can be useful if you have some static overhead that is the same for one or many messages (e.g. requesting a single line of input vs requesting multiple lines of input).

Have this explanation of the scheduler https://rakyll.org/scheduler/.